# Find the 'best' upper bound

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B>0$, find the upper bound of
\begin{equation}
C:=A-\sqrt{A^2+B}.
\end{equation}

My attempt: Using the fact that $B>0$, then if $A\geq 0$, $C<0$; if $A<0$, then $C<2A$. Hence, $C<\min\{0,2A\}$.

However, is there a better upper bound that can be expressed in terms of both $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are variable and you don't want to express the *LEAST* upper bound in terms of *either* of them.

You want to find a value that is equal or larger than any value that $A- \sqrt {A+B}$ could be for *any* possible values of $A$ or $B$ and you want to find the *least* such value.  The *least* such value would mean that any small number is *not* an upper bound.

For example.  $527 > A-\sqrt {A^2+B}$ for all $A$ and $B$ so $527$ is *an* upper bound.  But it's not the least upper bound because $526< 527$ and $526$ is also an upper bound.

No $B > 0$ and $A^2 \ge 0$ so $A^2 + B > A^2$ and so $\sqrt{A^2 + B} > \sqrt A^2 = |A|$ so $A-\sqrt{A^2 + B} < A-\sqrt{A^2}= A-|A|$.  Now if $A > 0$ then $A-|A| = 0$ and if $A\le 0$ then $A-|A|=2A \le 0$ so either way $A-\sqrt{A^2+B} < A-\sqrt{A^2}=A-|A| \le 0$.

So $0$ is *an* upper bound.  And it's a heck of a smaller upper bound than either $527$ or $526$ were.  But is it the *least* upper bound?

Well, if it is then for any $e < 0$ then $e$ *can't* be an upper bound.  And the only way to show that $0$ is the least upper bound is to show that for any $e < 0$ we can find an $A$ and $B$ so that

$e < A-\sqrt{A^2 + B}$.  Can we find such an $A$ and $B$?

Well we can set $A =0$ and then we just need to find a $B> 0$ so that $e < -\sqrt{B}$ or in other words $0 < \sqrt {B} < |e|$.

Or in other words $B < e^2$.  We can always find such a number.  For example $B = \frac {e^2}4$.

Then if $e < 0$ then $e < 0- \sqrt{0+\frac {e^2}4}=-\frac {|e|}2 = \frac e2$.  So $e $ is not an upper bound.  But $0$ is an upper bound.

So $0$ is the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

A first remark : your result hasn't to depend neither on $A$, nor on $B$.

> > The **least** upper bound is $0$ (the adjective "least" is important because this upper bound is not attained).

Here is why :

As $B > 0$ : $A^2+B>A^2 \geq 0$. Therefore, as $\sqrt{}$ is an increasing function :

$$\sqrt{A^2+B} > \sqrt{A^2}=|A|\tag{1}$$

itself equivalent, by taking the opposite and reversing the inequality sign, to

$$-\sqrt{A^2+B} < -|A|\tag{2}$$

As a consequence, adding $A$ to (2) gives

$$A-\sqrt{A^2+B}<A-|A|\tag{3}$$

Knowing that the Right Hand Side of (3) is $ \leq 0$ (indeed, it is either equal to $2A$ if $A<0$ or equal to $0$ if $A \geq 0$), the **least upper bound** you are looking for is $0$ ; moreover it is never reached...

Remark : Bound $0$ would be reached if $B$ is allowed to take value $0$...

Comment: I am surprised that you haven't commented my solution, which has many common features with the solution you have selected...

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(A,B)=A - \sqrt{A^2+B}$. For any $B>0$, evaluate

$$f_A'(A,B) = 1-\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B}}>0$$

That is $f(A,B)$, as a function of $A$, is monotonically increasing. Thus, its upper bound can be found by letting $A\rightarrow \infty$, i.e.

$$f(A,B)<\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty} A - \sqrt{A^2+B}
=\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-B}{A +\sqrt{A^2+B}}=0$$